# Zero-cost abstractions: performance of for-loop vs. iterators

Tags: performance, rust

Reading the [Zero-cost abstractions](https://ruudvanasseldonk.com/2016/11/30/zero-cost-abstractions) and looking at [Introduction to rust: a low-level language with high-level abstractions](https://www.slideshare.net/yann_s/introduction-to-rust-a-lowlevel-language-with-highlevel-abstractions) I tried to compare two approaches to computing the dot product of a vector: one using a for loop and one using iterators.

```
#![feature(test)]

extern crate rand;
extern crate test;

use std::cmp::min;

fn dot_product_1(x: &[f64], y: &[f64]) -> f64 {
    let mut result: f64 = 0.0;
    for i in 0..min(x.len(), y.len()) {
        result += x[i] * y[i];
    }
    return result;
}

fn dot_product_2(x: &[f64], y: &[f64]) -> f64 {
    x.iter().zip(y).map(|(&a, &b)| a * b).sum::<f64>()
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod bench {
    use test::Bencher;
    use rand::{Rng,thread_rng};
    use super::*;

    const LEN: usize = 30;

    #[test]
    fn test_1() {
        let x = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0];
        let y = [2.0, 4.0, 6.0];
        let result = dot_product_1(&x, &y);
        assert_eq!(result, 28.0);
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_2() {
        let x = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0];
        let y = [2.0, 4.0, 6.0];
        let result = dot_product_2(&x, &y);
        assert_eq!(result, 28.0);
    }

    fn rand_array(cnt: u32) -> Vec<f64> {
        let mut rng = thread_rng();
        (0..cnt).map(|_| rng.gen::<f64>()).collect()

    }

    #[bench]
    fn bench_small_1(b: &mut Bencher) {
        let samples = rand_array(2*LEN as u32);
        b.iter(|| {
            dot_product_1(&samples[0..LEN], &samples[LEN..2*LEN])
        })
    }

    #[bench]
    fn bench_small_2(b: &mut Bencher) {
        let samples = rand_array(2*LEN as u32);
        b.iter(|| {
            dot_product_2(&samples[0..LEN], &samples[LEN..2*LEN])
        })
    }
}
```

The later of the links above claims that the version with the iterators should have similar performance "and actually be a little bit faster". However, when benchmarking the two, I get very different results:

```
running 2 tests
test bench::bench_small_loop ... bench:          20 ns/iter (+/- 1)
test bench::bench_small_iter ... bench:          24 ns/iter (+/- 2)

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 2 measured; 0 filtered out
```

So, where did the "zero-cost abstraction" go?

**Update:** Adding the `foldr` example provided by @wimh and using `split_at` instead of slices give the following result.

```
running 3 tests
test bench::bench_small_fold ... bench:          18 ns/iter (+/- 1)
test bench::bench_small_iter ... bench:          21 ns/iter (+/- 1)
test bench::bench_small_loop ... bench:          24 ns/iter (+/- 1)

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 3 measured; 0 filtered out
```

So it seems that the additional time comes directly or indirectly from constructing the slices inside the measured code. To check that it indeed was the case, I tried the following two approaches with the same result (here shown for `foldr` case and using `map` + `sum`):

```
#[bench]
fn bench_small_iter(b: &mut Bencher) {
    let samples = rand_array(2 * LEN);
    let s0 = &samples[0..LEN];
    let s1 = &samples[LEN..2 * LEN];
    b.iter(|| dot_product_iter(s0, s1))
}

#[bench]
fn bench_small_fold(b: &mut Bencher) {
    let samples = rand_array(2 * LEN);
    let (s0, s1) = samples.split_at(LEN);
    b.iter(|| dot_product_fold(s0, s1))
}
```

Comment: your code don't compile. how many time did you run launch the test ? `thread_rng().sample_iter(&Standard).take(LEN * 2).collect();` could replace `rand_array()`.

Comment: Very interesting! As far as [I can see](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/8HCeTI): (a) the `loop` version still has bound checks and (b) the assembly of the `iter` version checks if the length is a multiple of 4 and then uses a loop which munches 4 floats at once (partial loop unrolling). And still, I see roughly the same timings on my machine (20ms/23ms). Fairly consistently.

Comment: The semicolon at the end of the `dot_product_iter` call should be removed, otherwise, the compiler could decide to eliminate it entirely (it doesn't seem to, though).

Comment: Increasing `LEN` I find the run time gets closer and closer, and if I make both functions `#[inline(never)]` then the loop variant is always slower (the inline version probably can avoid the loop bound checks).

Comment: @DavidBrown When increasing `LEN`, iter get a net avantage.

Comment: @Stargateur I added the missing lines to make it compile using cut-n'-paste. I have launched the benchmark several times with about the same result (1ns up and down for both cases). The generation of the random array is not part of what is measured, but yes, you suggestion would work.

Comment: when I use `x.iter().zip(y).fold(0f64, |r, (&a, &b)| r + a * b)`, the iter version is never slower on my pc. (I have to store the result in the bench function, to avoid it fully optimized away (`result = dot_product_iter...`). (using the version before the last edit).

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt Yes, I compiled both the [iterator version](https://godbolt.org/z/Aj_vlg) and the [loop version](https://godbolt.org/z/SmB8ZG) and noted the same. What I don't understand is why they perform so differently even though the iterator version uses loop unrolling. For the pipeline, this should be very efficient, but for some reason it is not.

Comment: @DavidBrown I updated the post. I actually benchmarked the one without the semicolon but forgot to update the post I wrote. PTAL.

Comment: @wimh That is indeed very interesting. I would expect that the compiler should be able to combine the `sum` and `map` into what you wrote using `foldr`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems zero cost to me. I wrote your code slightly more idiomatically, using the same random values for both tests, and then tested multiple times:

```
fn dot_product_1(x: &[f64], y: &[f64]) -> f64 {
    let mut result: f64 = 0.0;
    for i in 0..min(x.len(), y.len()) {
        result += x[i] * y[i];
    }
    result
}

fn dot_product_2(x: &[f64], y: &[f64]) -> f64 {
    x.iter().zip(y).map(|(&a, &b)| a * b).sum()
}
```

```
fn rand_array(cnt: usize) -> Vec<f64> {
    let mut rng = rand::rngs::StdRng::seed_from_u64(42);
    rng.sample_iter(&rand::distributions::Standard).take(cnt).collect()
}

#[bench]
fn bench_small_1(b: &mut Bencher) {
    let samples = rand_array(2 * LEN);
    let (s0, s1) = samples.split_at(LEN);
    b.iter(|| dot_product_1(s0, s1))
}

#[bench]
fn bench_small_2(b: &mut Bencher) {
    let samples = rand_array(2 * LEN);
    let (s0, s1) = samples.split_at(LEN);
    b.iter(|| dot_product_2(s0, s1))
}
```

```
bench_small_1   20 ns/iter (+/- 6)
bench_small_2   17 ns/iter (+/- 1)

bench_small_1   19 ns/iter (+/- 3)
bench_small_2   17 ns/iter (+/- 2)

bench_small_1   19 ns/iter (+/- 5)
bench_small_2   17 ns/iter (+/- 3)

bench_small_1   19 ns/iter (+/- 3)
bench_small_2   24 ns/iter (+/- 7)

bench_small_1   28 ns/iter (+/- 1)
bench_small_2   24 ns/iter (+/- 1)

bench_small_1   27 ns/iter (+/- 1)
bench_small_2   25 ns/iter (+/- 1)

bench_small_1   28 ns/iter (+/- 1)
bench_small_2   25 ns/iter (+/- 1)

bench_small_1   28 ns/iter (+/- 1)
bench_small_2   25 ns/iter (+/- 1)

bench_small_1   28 ns/iter (+/- 0)
bench_small_2   25 ns/iter (+/- 1)

bench_small_1   28 ns/iter (+/- 1)
bench_small_2   17 ns/iter (+/- 1)
```

In 9 of the 10 runs, the idiomatic code was faster than the for loop. This was done on 2.9 GHz Core i9 (I9-8950HK)  with 32 GB RAM, compiled with `rustc 1.31.0-nightly (fc403ad98 2018-09-30)`.

Comment: Very interesting indeed. I consistently get 20 and 24 for the two benchmarks. Also using 1.31.0.

Comment: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6600U CPU @ 2.60GHz with 16 GB RAM.

Comment: I took your code and tried that on a different machine (Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4160 CPU @ 3.60GHz). For some reason, I get 20ns and 16ns. Why?

Comment: Note this is likely due to Rust adding inefficiencies into "normal" code, such as needing to do a bounds check on every array index operation. Raw iteration will always be faster in practice if done right.

Answer (score 3):

For fun, I rewrote the benchmark to use [criterion](https://crates.io/crates/criterion), a port of the Haskell benchmarking library.

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "mats-zero-cost-rust"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["mats"]

[dev-dependencies]
criterion = "0.2"
rand = "0.4"

[[bench]]
name = "my_benchmark"
harness = false
```

**benches/my_benchmark.rs**

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate criterion;
extern crate rand;

use std::cmp::min;

use criterion::Criterion;

use rand::{thread_rng, Rng};

const LEN: usize = 30;

fn dot_product_loop(x: &[f64], y: &[f64]) -> f64 {
    let mut result: f64 = 0.0;
    for i in 0..min(x.len(), y.len()) {
        result += x[i] * y[i];
    }
    return result;
}

fn dot_product_iter(x: &[f64], y: &[f64]) -> f64 {
    x.iter().zip(y).map(|(&a, &b)| a * b).sum()
}

fn rand_array(cnt: u32) -> Vec<f64> {
    let mut rng = thread_rng();
    (0..cnt).map(|_| rng.gen()).collect()
}

fn criterion_loop_with_slice(c: &mut Criterion) {
    c.bench_function("loop with slice", |b| {
        let samples = rand_array(2 * LEN as u32);
        b.iter(|| dot_product_loop(&samples[0..LEN], &samples[LEN..2 * LEN]))
    });
}

fn criterion_loop_without_slice(c: &mut Criterion) {
    c.bench_function("loop without slice", |b| {
        let samples = rand_array(2 * LEN as u32);
        let (s0, s1) = samples.split_at(LEN);
        b.iter(|| dot_product_loop(s0, s1))
    });
}

fn criterion_iter_with_slice(c: &mut Criterion) {
    c.bench_function("iterators with slice", |b| {
        let samples = rand_array(2 * LEN as u32);
        b.iter(|| dot_product_iter(&samples[0..LEN], &samples[LEN..2 * LEN]))
    });
}

fn criterion_iter_without_slice(c: &mut Criterion) {
    c.bench_function("iterators without slice", |b| {
        let samples = rand_array(2 * LEN as u32);
        let (s0, s1) = samples.split_at(LEN);
        b.iter(|| dot_product_iter(s0, s1))
    });
}

criterion_group!(benches, criterion_loop_with_slice, criterion_loop_without_slice, criterion_iter_with_slice, criterion_iter_without_slice);
criterion_main!(benches);
```

I observe these results;

```
kolmodin@blin:~/code/mats-zero-cost-rust$ cargo bench
   Compiling mats-zero-cost-rust v0.1.0 (/home/kolmodin/code/mats-zero-cost-rust)                                                                                                                                  
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 1.16s                                                                                                                                                                
     Running target/release/deps/my_benchmark-6f00e042fd40bc1d
Gnuplot not found, disabling plotting
loop with slice         time:   [7.5794 ns 7.6843 ns 7.8016 ns]                             
Found 14 outliers among 100 measurements (14.00%)
  1 (1.00%) high mild
  13 (13.00%) high severe

loop without slice      time:   [24.384 ns 24.486 ns 24.589 ns]                                
Found 3 outliers among 100 measurements (3.00%)
  2 (2.00%) low severe
  1 (1.00%) low mild

iterators with slice    time:   [13.842 ns 13.852 ns 13.863 ns]                                  
Found 6 outliers among 100 measurements (6.00%)
  1 (1.00%) low mild
  4 (4.00%) high mild
  1 (1.00%) high severe

iterators without slice time:   [13.420 ns 13.424 ns 13.430 ns]                                     
Found 12 outliers among 100 measurements (12.00%)
  1 (1.00%) low mild
  1 (1.00%) high mild
  10 (10.00%) high severe

Gnuplot not found, disabling plotting
```

Using `rustc 1.30.0 (da5f414c2 2018-10-24)` on an AMD Ryzen 7 2700X.

The iterator implementation gets similar results for using `slice` and `split_at`.

The loop implementation gets very different results. The version with slice is significantly faster.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I ran this in April 2023 on a Ryzen 3900X with the newest Rust compiler `rustc 1.68.2` and got these results: `loop with slice = 10.863 ns, loop without slice = 11.533 ns, iterators with slice = 10.984 ns, iterators without slice = 11.696 ns` - So yes, iterators and functional programming callbacks are zero-cost in Rust. **BEAUTIFUL! :)**